# Apache is trying to serve noindex.html but errorhandler for 403 is set different?

Tags: error-handling, apache, httpd.conf, custom-error-handling

So i have just set new Error Handlers in httpd.conf for custom error pages:

```
Alias "/error" "/var/www/error/"
    ErrorDocument 400 /error/error.php?code=400
    ErrorDocument 401 /error/error.php?code=401
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/error.php?code=403
```

But when i am trying to reach my forbidden subdomain (index.php) i get this:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

But if i try the subdomain/jskldfjkd (and subdomain/forbiddendic/ also) it gives the correct error page. In the error logs Apache sais it searches for noindex.html. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In welcome.conf was standing the following:

```
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/noindex.html
</LocationMatch>
```

I removed it, and now it works :)

Comment: It looks like this triggers whenever you do a "Forbidden" on the index page (for any reason - e.g. mod_rewrite with [F] flag)